# TextField as3 getting the input

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have a problem witch i cant solve, and i wanted to ask what am i doing wrong. The idea should be that when i create the textfield i want to read from it, but it doesnt

```
function click2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2);
    fx=e.target.x+400;
    fy=e.target.y+300;
    var i:int;
    i=2;
    trace(str);
    trace(e.target.name);
    var  line:Shape = new Shape();
    line.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xFF0000,2);
    line.graphics.moveTo(sx,sy);
    line.graphics.lineTo(fx,fy);
    this.addChild(line);
    var inputField:TextField = new TextField();
    inputField.border = true;
    inputField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    inputField.width = 23;
    inputField.height = 18;
    inputField.x = (sx+fx)/2;
    inputField.y = (sy+fy)/2;
    inputField.multiline = false;
    inputField.maxChars = 3;
    inputField.restrict = "0-9"; 
    str=inputField.text;
    addChild(inputField);
}
```

In this code i create a line, and near it appears a textfield , where you need to input the value of the line, but i can`t get it , when i want to trace the STR value, it is null,the text should be written by the user and i should read it ...

Comment: You do not assign any text to your textfield. So why should there be something in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the data the user added to the textinput you have to listen for the change-event. After that you can access the provided text.

```
function click2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    ...
    inputfield.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkInput);
}

function checkInput(e:Event):void {
    //receive input value and validate it
    var textfield:TextField = e.target as TextField;
    var str:String = textfield.text;
    ...
}
```